# better way to intercept requests that nodejs further make

Tags: node.js, express, interceptor

I have created a nodejs server A with the express framework. I have used `request-promise` module to make http requests to different server B. Browser makes call to server A with cookie data. This cookie contains the jwt token that I further want to pass to server B.

```
@Get("/users")
getUsers( @Cookie('token') token: any): any {
    let usersPromise = Users.getUsers(jwt);
    return Promise.all([usersPromise])
        .then(response => {
            return response.users;

        });
}
```

I have created a `Users` class that further call server B using the request-promise module. One way is to pass the jwt token directly to every calls like this as I did in

```
let usersPromise = Users.getUsers(jwt);
```

is there any other way some intercept way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) package to intercept my all the request and appended the jwt to header.

TO configure this

Install `superagent` and `superagent-use` modules

```
npm install superagent superagent-use --save
```

Require the modules

```
var request = require('superagent-use')(require('superagent'));
```

Then define the superagent middleware

```
// interceptor used by superagent to add jwt in header for each request
request.use((req) => {
    req.header.jwt = jwt;
    return req;
});
```

and then to make calls

```
request
  .get(url)
  .query({ view: 'jsonView' });
```

`Superagent` is more useful than the `request-promise` as this module provide the **promise** and **rxjs** base apis , **url prefix** and an **elegant way to append querystring**.